# Cordova apps hangs when started after exiting with back button when using jquery-mobile-1.1.0-rc1

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I recently upgraded my apps  from jquery-mobile-1.0.1  to  jquery-mobile-1.1.0-rc1. Everything was working properly in jquery-mobile-1.0.1  but when using jquery-mobile-1.1.0-rc1  my  apps hangs when re-started after exiting with back button.

Note: The apps are started without issues the firts time after a fresh install.

I get same results  using phonegap-1.4.1 or cordova-1.5.0

Today after a few hours of debugging  I realized that if I add an id to my body tag  in my index.html

Before:

```
<body onload="init();">
```

After:

```
<body onload="init();" id="stage">
```

and add the following to my css

```
#stage {
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

Then my apps work properly with jquery-mobile-1.1.0-rc1.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Jquery Mobile 1.1RC1 is unstable. Did you check the issues section on github?

Comment: yes, I did look and nothing. At this point I'm wondering if I'm the only one who has encountered this problem.

Comment: Be a pal and submit the bug :)

Answer (score 0):

why not create a div and give THAT the id of stage and apply styling to the div?

Comment: That doesn't work and even if it did it wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with jquery-mobile-1.1.0-rc2 that was released yesterday and it looks like its fixed!